# Performing Functions on a Dynamically Created Table

Tags: javascript, dynamic-tables

I am retrieving 30 bakery items from a mySQL database into a dynamic HTML table using PHP.  The data retrieved are **Product**, **Item** (Primary Key), **Weight**, and **Price**.  My code also creates an INPUT box, called **Quantity**, for each item so that the user can type in how many cases he wants.  Below is a segment of the code used to generate the dynamic table:

```
        $i=0;

    while ($i < $num) {
        $Item=mysql_result($result,$i,"Item");
        $Product=mysql_result($result,$i,"Product");
        $Weight=mysql_result($result,$i,"Weight");
        $BGPrice=mysql_result($result,$i,"BGPrice");

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$Product</td>";
    echo "<td><INPUT NAME=Item size=5 value=$Item READONLY></td>";
    echo "<td><INPUT NAME=Weight size=5 value=$Weight READONLY></td>";
    echo "<td><INPUT NAME=Price size=5 value=$BGPrice READONLY></td>";
    echo "<td><INPUT NAME=Quantity size=5 value=0 tabindex=$i></td>";
    echo "<td><INPUT NAME=ExtPrice size=5 value=0 READONLY></td>";
    echo "<td><INPUT NAME=TotalWt size=5 value=0 READONLY></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $i++;
    }
```

I need JavaScript to call a function and calculate the values for Extended Price (**ExtPrice**) and Total Weight (**TotalWt**) as soon as the user enters the number of cases he would like to order.

Here's my struggle: there are 30 items in this dynamic table and each item's INPUT NAME is the same.  How can I create a function that updates **ExtPrice** and **TotalWt** for each individual product?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript should not directly reference each `input` by name. Instead, obtain a reference to the adjacent cells in the same row.

Assuming you have a submit button that re-calculates the results, here's an example:

```
document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var i, row;
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    // process each row individually
    for (i = 0, row; row = rows[i++];) {
        totalsForRow(row);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// updates the totals for each row
function totalsForRow(tr) {
    var j, inp, fields = {};
    var inputs = tr.getElementsByTagName("input");
    if (!inputs || inputs.length === 0)
        return;
    // map each input by name
    for (j = 0; inp = inputs[j++];) {
        fields[inp.name] = inp;
    }
    // update totals for this row, using the stored ref to the input
    fields.TotalWt.value = fields.Weight.value * fields.Quantity.value;
    fields.ExtPrice.value = fields.Price.value * fields.Quantity.value;
}
```

This doesn't do any error checking and could be improved in several ways. It's just meant to illustrate one approach.

See a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/C6PWH/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$i` variable to uniquely identify each input

`echo "<td><INPUT NAME=Item id='item$i' size=5 value='$Item' READONLY></td>";`

And as a side note use quotes or double quotes to wrap `$Item` as it may contains spaces, etc..